# pywin32 において dispatch 対象の調べ方

Tags: python, windows

例えばpywin32を使用してエクセルを操作する際は以下のようにすると思います。
`Excel.Application` の部分はどうやって調べるのでしょう？

任意のアプリが操作可能ならどの文字列で指定するのか。
というを調べるのはどのようにすればいいいですか？

```
import win32com.client
xlApp =　win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
```

Comment: この辺の記事を参考に。[progid](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/windows/attributes/progid?view=msvc-160), [WSHのCreateObject関数の引数のCOM識別子「ProgID」「CLSID」（GUID）とは何なのか解説。Windows内のActiveXオブジェクトを一覧表示して確認するコマンド](https://computer-technology.hateblo.jp/entry/2016/01/06/WSH%E3%81%AECreateObject%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0%E3%81%AE%E5%BC%95%E6%95%B0%E3%81%AECOM%E8%AD%98%E5%88%A5%E5%AD%90%E3%80%8CProgID%E3%80%8D%E3%80%8CCLSID%E3%80%8D%EF%BC%88GUID%EF%BC%89%E3%81%A8)

Answer (score 1):

> 任意のアプリが操作可能なら

いいえ、アプリケーション側がスクリプト制御可能なオブジェクトを提供している必要があります。Excelについては`Excel.Application`ということになります。

> `Excel.Application`の部分はどうやって調べるのでしょう？

[Office VBA リファレンス / Application オブジェクト](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/excel.application(object)) から辿っていくことになります。他のアプリケーションもそれぞれオブジェクト機能が提供され、尚且つそのドキュメントが提供されている場合はそれを参照することになります。一般的な方法はありません。珍しいところだとAppleのiTunesなんかもありました（今探しても公式ドキュメントは見当たりませんでしたが…）